# How to find the identical rows based on one column and label them into groups

Tags: matlab

I have a bigdata in the form of a table:

```
    Filename    A     B
    xxxxx       1     2
    xxxxx       3     4   
    xxxxx       5     5 
    xxxxx       6     .
    xxxxx       .     .
    yyyyy       .     .
    yyyyy
    yyyyy
    yyyyy
    zzzzz
    zzzzz
```

I need to scan the first column for all the rows(10,000 rows approx) and see where the filename changes and create a label for every unique filename. In this way I would have another column created with the labels generated .

```
  file filename  A     B
    1      xxxxx
           xxxxx
           xxxxx
    2      yyyyy
           yyyyy
           yyyyy
    3      zzzzz
           zzzzz
```

Also I need to find the maximum value in column A for each unique file(file 1, file 2...) . Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a sample [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) like in your example:

```
T = 

    Filename    A     B
    ________    __    _

    'xxxxx'      4    4
    'xxxxx'      6    2
    'xxxxx'      1    8
    'xxxxx'      1    4
    'xxxxx'      6    6
    'yyyyy'      8    2
    'yyyyy'     10    7
    'yyyyy'      2    3
    'yyyyy'      6    7
    'zzzzz'      5    7
    'zzzzz'      1    8
```

We can extract the first column of file names and use the function [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to create a set of indices (i.e. labels) for each unique file. We can then create a table from this vector of labels and concatenate it with our existing table:

```
[~, ~, index] = unique(T.Filename, 'stable');
T = [table(index, 'VariableNames', {'Label'}) T];

T = 

    Label    Filename    A     B
    _____    ________    __    _

    1        'xxxxx'      4    4
    1        'xxxxx'      6    2
    1        'xxxxx'      1    8
    1        'xxxxx'      1    4
    1        'xxxxx'      6    6
    2        'yyyyy'      8    2
    2        'yyyyy'     10    7
    2        'yyyyy'      2    3
    2        'yyyyy'      6    7
    3        'zzzzz'      5    7
    3        'zzzzz'      1    8
```

We can then use this label vector with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to collect the maximum value of column `A` for each unique file:

```
maxVals = accumarray(T.Label, T.A, [], @max)

maxVals =

     6    % For file 1
    10    % For file 2
     5    % For file 3
```